# PHP - Create thumbnail from picture without having white/black bars (and keeping proportion)

Tags: php, image

I want to create a thumbnail for an image so that it's a square with no black bars/white bars and it fills the whole square while maintaining proportion. Kind of like CSS `background-size: cover`.

Like this:

[image]

Even if the image is smaller than the tuhmbnail size (which is arbitrary) it should still create the thumbnail.

The thumbnail size should be 400x400 (px).

I actually wrote a function to create a thumbnail with the white bars, here it is:

```
function createThumbnail($orig, $sizes){
    $width = $sizes[0];
    $height = $sizes[1];

    $targetSize = 340;

    $targetWidth = ($width > $height) ? $targetSize : round(($width * $targetSize) / $height);
    $targetHeight = ($width > $height) ? round(($height * $targetSize) / $width) : $targetSize;

    $targetLayer = imagecreatetruecolor($targetSize, $targetSize);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($targetLayer, 255, 255, 255);

    imagefill($targetLayer, 0, 0, $color);

    $targetX = ($width > $height) ? 0 : ($targetSize - $targetWidth) / 2;
    $targetY = ($width > $height) ? ($targetSize - $targetHeight) / 2 : 0;

    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer, $orig, $targetX, $targetY, 0, 0, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $width, $height);

    return $targetLayer;
}
```

But I can't figure out a way to crop them and have them accomodated as I want. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some back and forth I actually came up with a solution, probably not the best or most efficient, I have yet to test it for all cases but it seems to work for now:

```
function createThumbnail($orig, $sizes){
    $width = $sizes[0];
    $height = $sizes[1];

    $targetSize = 400;

    $srcX = 0;
    $srcY = 0;
    $src = $width;

    if ($width > $height){
        $ratio = $targetSize / $height;
        $srcX = (($ratio * $width) - $targetSize) / (2 * $ratio);
        $src = $height;
    }else if ($height > $width){
        $ratio = $targetSize / $width;
        $srcY = (($ratio * $height) - $targetSize) / (2 * $ratio);
    }

    $targetLayer = imagecreatetruecolor($targetSize, $targetSize);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($targetLayer, 255, 255, 255);

    imagecopyresampled($targetLayer, $orig, 0, 0, $srcX, $srcY, $targetSize, $targetSize, $src, $src);

    return $targetLayer;
}
```

If someone has a better solution or knows how to improve this one please let me know!